# Need Regular expression that should minimum 6 to 25 digits and special charectres

Tags: regex, angular

I have a textbox where I need a regex expression to restrict the input to these conditions:

- At least 6 characters min
- At most 25 chacters
- May begin with special characters

I have this so far `^(\+\d{1,3}[-+()., ]?)?\d{6,25}$`

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Present i am using this ^(\+\d{1,3}[-+()., ]?)?\d{6,25}$ regex it is not satisfying 123456 or +123456 or -123456 or (123456) or .123456 or ,123456 these cond itions

Comment: `^.{6,25]$` may be?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this maybe `^([-+(,.]?)[\d]{6,25}([)]?)`

- `^` beginning of string
- `[-+(,.]?` will match the special characters
- `[\d]` will allow only digits
- `([)]?)` can have and ending `)`
- `6` specifies the min value
- `25` is your max value

As a tip, great website for testing regex is https://regex101.com/

Comment: The text need to be like below format                                                                                                   123456 or +123456 or -123456 or (123456) or .123456 or ,123456 Need to be 6 digits must

Comment: @sathishKumarGalla something like this maybe `^[-+(,.\d]{6,25}`

Comment: Yes it is working for me but allowing 6 special characters also like ++++++  but i need only 6 digits will allow. Digits must and should 6 needed

Comment: What about this? `^([-+(,.]?)[\d]{6,25}([)]?)`

Comment: @sathishKumarGalla did this work for you? Or did you find a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this one, might helpfull or give some hint.

```
/\b(0?[6-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5]|[-@./#&+\w\s])\b/g
```